# Do we need to install elastic-search while using searchkick in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I am using `searchkick` gem in rails. While doing searching in localhost I am getting error like:

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed in SalesController#index
Connection refused - Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200 (localhost:9200)
```

Do we need to install elastic search to get search functionality of `searchkick` in rails

Comment: Of course yes, maybe not installed, but running in somewhere.

Comment: how to run elastic search in ubuntu  without installing

Comment: Just download it and run the bin file, or use Docker. That's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. If you do not which to install it in your machine I will recommend you to run it with docker. It is as simple as running the following commands:

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
```

That will be all! Lastly, if you don't already know set your ELASTICSEARCH_URL environment variable to the route where elasticsearch is running and you are good to go.

Have in mind that this is a development configuration. If you which to run it in a production environment you must read the official documentation at [Install Elasticsearch with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker).